# IEEE 754 multiplication small numbers

Tags: floating-point, ieee-754

I want to multiply this two number:

00100010000000000000000000000000 (1.73472347598e-18)

and

00010101000000000000000000000001 (-2.997414069111348324895269018E-38)

The rule is:

(e1-127) +e2

So the exponent is

(68 - 127) + 42 = -17

-17 Cant be representet in IEEE754 Format

This calculator, says that the exponent is -126.
But how can I calculate this by hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st: Corrections

`00010101000000000000000000000001` is not `-2.997414069111348324895269018E-38`, but `2.58493972238e-26`.
See [IEEE-754 Floating Point Converter](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html)

---

The product of `1.73472347598e-18 * 2.58493972238e-26` is about `4.48416e-44` or in hex/binary expo notation `0x1.0000002p-144`.  -144 - (-127) is the sought after -17.

> how can I calculate this by hand?
> says that the exponent is -126

"-17 Cant be represented in IEEE754 Format" is not quite true.

The product is less than the smallest *normalized* value (biased exponent less than 1), yet larger than the smallest *sub-normal* value.  The [IEEE format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format#Exponent_encoding) sacrifices precision for extended range for tiny values.  Increase the -17 to 1 (that is the biased exponent of -126) and shift the significand `0x1.000002` 18 right.

```
s eeeeeeee mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
0 00000000 00000000000000000100000
```

+0.00000000000000000100000<sub>2</sub>*2<sup>1-127</sup>

When the encoded biased exponent is 0, interpret the encoding as if the biased exponent was 1, yet the implied 1 bit is now a 0.

Comment: I dont really understand why I should shift 18 right. At -126 biased exponent I have two modes. When the exponent is 0 then the first char is a 0 and when the exponent is 1 then the first char is a 1. So I thought to shift only 17 times to right.

Comment: @wwwwwwwwwwww Without using _sub-normal_ numbers, the smallest _normalized_ value is 1.0*2^-126 encoded as `0 00000001 (1.)00000000000000000000000`..  To encode 1.0*2^-127, we shift right once:  0.1*2^-126  and encode as `0 00000000 (0.)10000000000000000000000` We need to encode 4.48416e-44 or 1.0*2^-144 or with the 1 shifted 18 times right is 0.000'000'000'000'000'001*2^-126 and encoded as `0 00000000 (0.)00000000000000000100000`.

Comment: @wwwwwwwwwwww " At -126 biased exponent I have ..."  --> The_biased exponent_ is 8 bits with values 0 to 255.  When it is 0, the binary exponent is -126.  When it is [1...254], the binary exponent is `biased exponent - 127`.